# User added to a group that have Contribute permision, is not granted a contribute permision

Tags: 2013, permissions, site-collection

I did the following:-

1. I create a new web application that uses NTL windows authentication.
2. Inside this web application I have created a new wildcard managed path named “DiscussionForum”.
3. Inside the managed path I have created a new site collection of type community site.
4. Then I have a test user named "contributor" inside my Active directory.
5. I tried to access the site collection using this user and I got the following message, which seems logical since this user was not grant any permission on this site collection :-
   **Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.**
6. Then I login using the site collection admin, I went to à setting àsite setting-> user& permissionà site permission .
7. I created a new group which contain the “contributor” user and i have granted this group a contribute permission level.
8. But when I try to login to the site collection using the “contributor ” username , still he got the same message :-

**Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.**

Although this user should be a contributor to this site collection!, any idea what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the zones in central admin that it is not explicitly denying access to users.

Kind Regards,
JP

Comment: i found that users lack permissions on the AD . i do not know why permission on AD affect the user permission on SP.?